# Crash on presentPopoverFromRect

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, uipopovercontroller

I have subclass the UIButton

in the init method I added the target to button

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(openList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

in the openList

```
[listPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:self.frame
                          inView:self.superview
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                          animated:YES];
```

but application on presentPopoverFromRect (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`)

[image]

Comment: i think you need to change - self.view.superview instead of self.superview in presentPopoverFromRect method

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS means something you expect to be (valid) isn't. Check self.superView

Comment: @rishi I have also tried self.superview . . .

Comment: @AndreiStoleru you are right. I check the NSLog(frame of self.superview.frame) . . So I think every object is valid here..

Comment: @AmitBattan - yes, that is what i feel is wrong, you need to use self.view.superview.

Comment: self is button here, I don't think we need self.view .. even I try toset a property 'UIView *viewForPopOver;` and used viewForPopOver instead of `self.superview` but same result

Comment: Have you enabled NSZombie to check which exact instance is creating issue, might be something in table view is causing this issue.

Comment: Yes Thanks @Rishi I was using `@property (readwrite, assign) NSArray *listArray;` changed assign to retain . . . how I accept answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `NSZombie` to check which exact instance is creating issue, it seems like there is some issue in table view.

Comment: Yes Rishi, I was using `@property (readwrite, assign) NSArray *listArray;` I changed `assign` to `retain`

Answer (score 2):

Error:

```
UIPopoverController* pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init]];
    [pop presentPopoverFromRect:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame inView:tableView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

No error:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController* pop;
@synthesize pop = _pop;

pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init]];
    [pop presentPopoverFromRect:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame inView:tableView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(![listPopOver isPopoverVisible]){

    listPopOver = [[listPopOverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"listPopOverViewController" bundle:nil];
    listPopOver.viewDelegate=self;
    listPopOver = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:PopOver] retain];
    [listPopOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(670.0f, 380.0f)];
    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [listPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(50, 160, 670, 380) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0
                                     animated:YES]; 
    }
else{

    [listPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```